# iPhone stops charging after unlocking to use accessories

Tags: windows, iphone, ios

I have searched all over the internet, and can not seem to find anything. I was hoping someone here had experience this problem. Recently, every time I plug my iPhone into my computer it says its charging, Then when I unlock my phone it stops charging, and seems to not connect to my computer. It has done this with 4 other iPhones, so I believe it has something to do with my computer. I have updated all my USB drives, they are seem to be working fine. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: You have Windows as a tag - are you experiencing this problem on a PC running Windows? If so, please indicate which model of PC, and which version of Windows.

Comment: It is an HP Notebook 15-ay011nr laptop, and running windows 10.